# How to get Information out of a loop reading a html?

Tags: python, asynchronous, playwright

im trying to get out the information of a constantly running browser, if i do a print of table_list it works ... but i want to call open_browser() and get something back to work with

```
import asyncio
import playwright
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

async def open_browser(self):
    async with async_playwright() as p:            
            self.browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
            self.page = await self.browser.new_page()
            await self.page.goto('https://testpage/#Index')  
            
            # i tried many ways to let the browser open ... this is the one that works           
            while True:
                await asyncio.sleep(20)
                table_list = values() <-- **HOW TO GET THIS 'table_list' Information???**

async def values ():
  print('Try to read the table')
        while True:                        
            try:
               result = await self.page.inner_html('tbody')                
               tbody = BeautifulSoup(result,features="html.parser")
            except:
               print('Cant read the table - retry endless')
               continue
            
            # read the content
            table_list = {}            
            # etc... do something in the list <-- this already works
            
            try:                
                return list  
            except: 
                print ('Cant print the table - retry forever')
                continue
```

Comment: You should be using an `await` when calling 'values'?

Comment: Sorry, i´ve changed something from my code to make it easier to read. There is an await already. The problem is i want to make some multiple Tasks and dont want to wait till the "while" loop stops. So i have an asyncio.ensure.future(open_browser).

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer ...

open a second asyncio.ensure_future() with a new definition that asks constantly for new values.

```
async def read_the_values_from_while_loop():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        x = classname.value
        print(x)


asyncio.ensure_future(open_browser())
asyncio.ensure_future(read_the_values_from_while_loop())
loop.run_forever()
```

sorry for my unconcrete question ... was my first ;), try to improve